# How to send 1 request per 5 mins to store bearer token

Tags: k6

I need to send 1 request every 5 mins to store a bearer token inside of a variable so i can use it for the actual performance tests.

How would i go about doing this as i've tried using the rate and timeunit options. This will need to run once every 5 mins as i will have tests running longer than this so needs to be able to update with the latest token.

Tried setting timeunits and rates but it just seems to ignore these and the 1 VU will carry on to send 500+ requests within the 5 mins

Comment: Each VU is independent from all other VUs, so you cannot easily share data between them. You could have your VU keep track of when the token expires and then refresh on the next run. This is going to influence your metrics/stats a little bit, but if it only occurs once every 5 minutes, it should be negligible (and you can always filter out those requests by (not) tagging them).